# Subuser Docker firefox image

Tags: linux, firefox, docker

I followed all the steps to create subuser given on subuser.org

I am not able to create firefox image and not able to restrict the access to the Downloads folder as given in the video and documentation

Please provide me with the solution. i need it for my project

Comment: Could you add what you have tried?

Comment: Have you contacted: http://subuser.org/community.html

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZrs8KngN68

Comment: https://github.com/subuser-security/subuser

Answer (score 2):

The video that you found is old and the procedure has changed.

Presently, you can do the following:

To install firefox from the official images use.

```
$ subuser subuser add myfirefox iceweasel@default
```

While installing, you will be prompted to edit firefox's permissions. If you chose to edit them, you can dissable access to the Dowloads directory.

You can edit firefox's permissions at any time by running.

```
$ subuser subuser myfirefox
```

To run the subuser do

```
$ subuser run myfirefox
```

You can add firefox to your path, so that you'll be able to run it by running the "myfirefox" command without `subuser run` by doing:

```
$ subuser subuser add-to-path myfirefox
```

It is also possible to create your own firefox image, perhaps based on ubuntu.

First create a subuser repository:

```
$ mkdir my-subuser-images
$ subuser pkg init
```

Now create a firefox image

```
$ subuser pkg add firefox
```

First you will be propted to select `firefox`'s permissions by filling out the JSON form. Then you will be asked to create a `SubuserImagefile`. The format is the same as for a `Dockerfile`.

To create a subuser based on your new image you can do

```
$ subuser subuser add myfirefox firefox@./
```

The `@./` means to install the firefox image from the current directory.

You can publish your image by turning your subuser repository into a git repository and uploading it somewhere like github.

If you do that. Then people will be able to use your image by creating subusers like this:

```
$ subuser subuser add myfirefox firefox@https://github.com/ankita/my-subuser-images
```

When you update your repository, your users will be able to easilly update the images that they got from you with the command:

```
$ subuser update all
```